# Sphinx Latex break line autodoc

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, line-breaks, autodoc

I am making my python docs with sphinx-apidoc.
But some text seems messed up because the line does not break in certain cases.

[image]

I have tried to set latex_elements on config.py with preamble, but the result is the same. You can also see that the methods table also is a little confusing with a word in front of the other.

```
latex_elements = {
    'papersize': 'a4paper',
    'pointsize': '12pt',
    'figure_align': 'htbp',
    'preamble': r'''
    \usepackage[draft]{minted}
    \fvset{breaklines=true}
    ''',
}
```

Have you had the same problem ?

Comment: You could try to set `add_module_names` to `False`; https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/usage/configuration.html#confval-add_module_names

Comment: Do not solve the problem. Just delete part of the content.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393710/sphinx-automodule-no-text-wrap-in-class-name-latexpdf/63792054#63792054

Comment: Interesting. I had to delete my html build for `add_module_names` to take effect there. For LaTeX, it works without having to delete anything.