# Sphinx automodule, no text wrap in class name (latexpdf)

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, pdflatex

I'm generating pdf using make latexpdf of Sphinx. This mostly works fine but I have a quite deep folder structure for my project resulting in class names that do not fit on the page. Anyone who knows how I can tackle this?

Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/60251546/407651

Comment: Thanks, didn't stumble upon it when I was Googling, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I hope you found the solution if not add the code below in the *preamble* of your `conf.py`

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\pysigline}[1]{%
                                            
\setlength{\py@argswidth}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\linewidth\relax}%

\item[{\parbox[t]{\py@argswidth}{\raggedright#1}}]}

 \renewcommand{\pysiglinewithargsret}[1]{%
                                           
 \setlength{\py@argswidth}{\dimexpr\labelwidth+\linewidth\relax}%

 \item[{\parbox[t]{\py@argswidth}{\raggedright#1}}]}
                                            
\makeatother
```

Comment: Honestly didn't figure it out by then, I'll revisit it probably this month. Thanks!